# How to push down an element in a table - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table with 10 rows, and per example I hide the row 1,2,3 , how can I push the rows I hide down to others appears like that :

row4-row5-row6-row7-row8-row9-row10-row1-row2-row3

Comment: Remove the row and append it to the bottom of the table's tbody.

Comment: You could grab the hidden rows, remove them and append them to the table.

Comment: do you have a hide button ? in the Table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the rows and append them to the end of the tbody.

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector("#table tbody");
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("#table tbody tr");
tbody.appendChild(trs[0]);
tbody.appendChild(trs[1]);
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```